# Parametros NULL peticion POST HttpClient Angular

Tags: angular, net

La versión de Angular es (Angular CLI version (7.3.3))

Realizo la llamada desde login.component.ts.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],

})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {

    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let resultado: Object;

    var data: LoginData = {

      usuario: "a",
      contrasena: "b"
                        }

    http.post(baseUrl + 'api/Login/LoginPOST/',data, { headers: headers }).subscribe(result => {
    }, error => console.error(error));


  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}

interface login {
  isLoggin: boolean;
}

export interface LoginData {
  usuario: string;
  contrasena: string;
}
```

Comment: Estas utilizando web api?

Comment: Estoy usando una Aplicación web ASP.NET Core con Angular.

Comment: Buenas. ¿Pudiste confirmar que efectivamente está yendo el data en tú petición? Para obtener una mejor ayuda podrías indicar la versión de Angular que estás utilizando e inclur el .ts completo de modo a ver los imports que estás realizando.

Comment: He modificado la pregunta incluyendo la versión de Angular utilizada y el archivo .ts

Answer (score 0):

en tu objeto data pasalo a formato json

```
var dataLogin=JSON.stringify({usuario:"a",contrasena:"b"});

http.post(baseUrl + 'api/Login/LoginPOST/',   data: "LoginData =" + dataLogin, { headers: headers }).subscribe(result => {
}, error => console.error(error));
```

de ser posible utiliza la aplicacion Fiddler para analizar el todo el contenido de tu request.